# How to get timezone value

Tags: magento

how to get the timezone drop down menu in frontend magento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code to **get all timezones**:-

```
$timezones = Mage::getModel('core/locale')->getOptionTimezones();
echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r($timezones); 
echo "</pre>";
```

You will be getting an array. You can loop through the array and populate the **selection/dropdown list** like below:-

```
<select>
<?php
foreach($timezones as $timezone) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $timezone['value']; ?>"><?php echo $timezone['label']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Chapagain How to get Magento time zone which is set in the magento admin